# iOS:How to call didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo after the photo is taken from camera

Tags: ios10

I want to call didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo without using the choose image button or i want to get the event when picture is successfully taken from camera in uiimagepickercontroller.